# Onehotencoded dataframe won't join with original dataframe in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
train_df = pd.DataFrame({'home':['A','A','B','C','C'],'dest':['X','Y','Y','X','Y']})
```

If I do:

```
train_df[['home','dest']] = train_df[['home','dest']].astype('category')
    
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotenc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')   
 
encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(onehotenc.fit_transform(train_df[['home','dest']]).toarray())
encoded_df.columns = onehotenc.get_feature_names_out()
train_df = train_df.join(encoded_df)
```

I do get the train_df dataframe with encoded_df columns added on the right. However, if I do

```
for df in [train_df]:
  df[['home','dest']] = df[['home','dest']].astype('category')

  from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
  onehotenc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

  encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(onehotenc.fit_transform(df[['home','dest']]).toarray())
  encoded_df.columns = onehotenc.get_feature_names_out()
  df = df.join(encoded_df)
```

the train_df is same as before. Why does the assignment not work in the for loop case? I need to do similar encoding on multiple dataframes, and add encoded columns to those dataframes. How can I do it in a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `for ... in` is actually assigning object in list to new variable, so if you modify the variable, it doesn't affect object in list.

You can either append the modified object to a new list or replace the object in list with it.

```py
dfs = []

for df in [train_df]:
    ...
    dfs.append(df)

# or

dsf = [train_df]

for idx, df in enumerate(dfs):
    ...
    dfs[idx] = df
```

Comment: But I have been routinely doing modifications like df.drop('home',axis=1,inplace=True) or df['dest'][1] = 'P' within the for loop, and the changes reflect on the original variables (train_df). Is it only that I cannot do df = something?

Comment: @Tejas Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25670170/10315163.